# merging exceptions in try/except

Tags: python, exception, python-requests, pylint, try-except

I'm an experience Perl programmer relatively new to Python.

I'm writing a simple program which uses requests.get(), in a try/except block. pylint complains my bare 'except:' was too bare, so I made it 'except Exception:', but it makes the same complaint. Is there an alternative to catching all nine exceptions that can be generated in requests, considering I just display a message and quit?

I'm going to list all nine, but I wish there were a simpler way.

Comment: Maybe pylint is just being too picky?  It shouldn't be complaining about a bare exception if it isn't bare.

Comment: The second message when using `except Exception` is going to be [broad-exception-caught](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/messages/warning/broad-exception-caught.html) and not [bare-except](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/messages/warning/bare-except.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests

try:
    response = requests.get(request_link',headers=headers)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
```

This should be able to cover all exception of `requests`.

Comment: Thanks, Arunbh! Proving yet again that the information you need about anything python is out there, if only you can find it.